# Transition a circle from one point to another given x, y position with a pause at every point

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skantipu/ng3onnp2/) to transition a circle from point A to point B. But, how do I modify code to make it work if the 'move' method is called like below and also circle has to pause for a second at every point. Please help.

```
myBall.move(50,300).move(150,400).move(100,200).move(130,230);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing around I think I've managed to come up with what you were looking for, this creates a queue of move events which is pushed to each time `move` is called, this sequence of events is then run in order by the `run` function (note that I've added a `.move(0,0)` at the beginning, something strange happens running this in an SO snippet, this also adds a brief delay on SO, but it seems to work fine on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnatLqa6/) without it):

```js
function ball() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("ball");
  var q = [];
  var running = false;
  var me = this;

  this.move = function(x, y) {
    q.push([x, y]);

    if (!running) {
      running = true;
      me.run();
    }
    return this;
  }

  this.run = function() {
    if (q.length == 0) {
      running = false;
    } else {
      var pos = q.shift();
      elem.style.transform = `translate(${pos[0]}px, ${pos[1]}px)`;
      setTimeout(me.run, 2000);
    }
  }
}
let myBall = new ball();
myBall.move(0, 0).move(50, 300).move(150, 400).move(100, 200).move(130, 230);
```

```css
#ball {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="ball">
</div>
```